# How to get a form value in another form value submission

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, forms, razor

I had username and password in first form and retrieve password in another form , in which i want userame entered in first form in submission of second form.

```
 @model Network.Models.LoginDetail

    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
    <p>
        Please enter your user name and password. @Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register") if you don't have an account.
    </p>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index","Student",FormMethod.Post)) {
     <div>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Account Information</legend>

                <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Username)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Username)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
            </div>
            <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Log in" style="width: 200px"/>
            </p>
            @ViewBag.Message
            </fieldset>
             </div>
            }
            @using (Html.BeginForm("RetrievePassword","Student",FormMethod.Post)) {
            <p>
            Forgot password? <input type="submit" onclick="updateUsername();"value="Click Here" style="width: 150px"/> Entering your username to retrieve your password.
            </p>
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Username)
        }
```

How can we acheive this, i tried in javascript capturing of username in hiddenfield but not working.
Or can form within form be used to acheive this.
Please provide a solution.

Thanks,

Michaeld

Comment: Javascript is probably the way to do this. Let's see your javascript.

Comment: Hi Jasen, thanks for your input   document.getElementById('username').value = document.getElementById('Username').value;     worked i tried changing hidden value id name

Answer (score 0):

At the post method of "Index" action in "Stundent" controller you will be able to get the value either in formcollection or in LoginDetail object form.

**Example:**

```
public ActionRestult Index(FormCollection FC)
{
   string UserName = FC["Username"];
   string Password = FC["Password"];
}
```

**Or Alternatively**

```
public ActionRestult Index(LoginDetail obj)
{
   string UserName = obj.Username;
   string Password = obj.Password;
}
```

This will fix your concern.

Comment: second alt is getting null as both are in different forms , dint have much time to test as got solution with formcollection , thank you